# string literal contains an unescaped line break

Tags: javascript, php

I have an error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

```
'<ul>\n' +
'<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++){
        echo '<li onclick="updateBasket('.$i.','+value['basketID'].')"><?= $i ?></li>';
    }
?>'+
'</ul>\n' +
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing JavaScript and PHP syntax in the `<?php` block. Did you mean `.$value['basketID']`?

Comment: Look at this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIR1F.png

Comment: You can't use JavaScript values in your PHP code! If you just need to repeat the `onclick` statement 30 times, then simply do the loop in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will replace your PHP loop with the same thing but in JavaScript. Replace everything including the lines that open and close the `<ul>`.

```
// End previous concatenation.
'<ul>\n';
// Insert 30 list items.
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    tr += '<li onclick="updateBasket(' + i + ', ' + value['basketCount'] + ')">' + i + '</li>';
// Continue your concatenation as before.
tr +=
'</ul>\n' +
```